# Does the POTUS have priority for organ transplants?

Tags: united-states, president

If the POTUS needed an organ transplant, then does the POTUS have priority and would end up as number 1 in the organ wait lists? Or would he be treated like any other person in this matter?

Comment: This has already been asked at [law.se]: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64534/is-the-president-at-the-top-of-all-organ-waiting-lists/64544#64544

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated [on a different site](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/64539/37717), law 5.4.A of the laws listed [here](https://optn.transplant.hrsa.gov/governance/policies/) would prevent this, because the law says:

> Allocation of deceased donor organs must not be influenced positively or negatively by political influence, national origin, ethnicity, sex, religion, or financial status.

And status as a president is likely defined as political influence.

However, there are two other possible workarounds for this brought up in other parts of this question.
[this comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64534/is-the-president-at-the-top-of-all-organ-waiting-lists/64544#comment135530_64539) mentions the possibility of a direct donation of organs, and [another answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/64544/37717) shows that since the president can travel easily, they can sign up at more hospitals, increasing their chances of getting an organ.